# How to determine if an element to the right or left of a range?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a simple method to determine if an integer is to the right or the left of a range.

The << or >> range operators would be perfect but they only appear to work range to range. Is there something similar that works with element to the range?

such as, 
    `SELECT 8 >> int4range(4,7)`

with a boolean result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions [`lower()`, `upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html), e.g.:

```
select 
    8 > upper(int4range(4,7)) as greater, 
    2 < lower(int4range(4,7)) as less

 greater | less 
---------+------
 t       | t
(1 row)
```